# Javascript getElementsByName not working?

Tags: javascript

I have a function like this

```
function f(el){
   var a = el.getElementsByName("name");
}
```

but I am getting  "el.getElementsByName is not a function" error
I know that I can use `arguments` for this but what if I want to do it like the method above? Thanks!
Also no jQuery please

Comment: what is `el`? `document`?

Comment: it should be getElementById

Comment: title and content in your post does not match....

Comment: This makes no sense, there's no context, no explanation ?

Comment: what is your html and how are you calling the `f` function. Also your code does not use `getElementById`

Comment: @Nina it's a whatever DOM structure I pass in the function.

Comment: Several problems here. You are not showing us the function call that gives the error and why are you using `getElementsByName` and asking for `getElementsById`?

Comment: getElementsByName doesn´t work for nodes, only document.getElementsByName

Comment: @sergio0983 thank you for an actual answer.Also note to other ppl: `getElementByiD` isn't mentioned anywhere in my question??

Comment: @Pear It was before your question was edited....

Comment: @user1289451 the only edit I made was adding the error message... well if it actually was id my bad then

Comment: @Pear Original title: *"JS: getElementById not working?"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, you are using that function on nodes, and this is a document function, not a DOMnode function.

However, you could use this one:

```
function f(el){
   var a = el.querySelector("[name='name']");
}
```